# What happens when you print a Swift object (po) in lldb?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, swift, lldb

In `Objective-C`, when you `NSLog` an object or `po` it in `lldb`, the object receives the `description` message.

In Swift however, the behaviour seems to be different. I implemented both `Printable` (requires `description` property) and `DebugPrintable` (which requires in turn a property named `debugDescription`). If I try to `println()` an object or `po` it, none of those properties gets called.

What's going on? What are those protocols for then??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a known issue that `Printable` is ignored by the Swift REPL (i.e., anything in a Playground or run by `xcrun swift` at the command line) but recognized by the compiler (compiled apps in the simulator or `xcrun swiftc`).

For example, here's the code of "foo.swift":

```
struct Person : Printable {
    let name: String

    var description: String {
        return "\(name)"
    }
}

let me = Person(name: "Nate")
println(me)
```

If I run it using the REPL, I get this:

```
$ xcrun swift foo.swift 
foo.Person
```

But if I compile it first, and then run it, it uses the `description` computed property:

```
$ xcrun -sdk macosx swiftc foo.swift ; ./foo
Nate
```

---

The `DebugPrintable` protocol is useful if you want to be able to use the `debugPrint` and `debugPrintln` functions -- in compiled code, they print out an instance's `debugDescription` property.

Comment: Who would have thought... Thanks! ;-)

Comment: BTW, if this actually description, is there any reason to implement DebugPrintable?

Comment: @cfisher I have no idea! :)

Answer (score 4):

Just to add a few more details to Nate's answer:

- in Xcode 6, when you try to "po" a Swift object, one of two things happen:

  - the object is actually an Objective-C object (e.g. NSWindow, NSString), or an optional of such type. In this case, LLDB unwraps if necessary, and then calls NSPrintForDebugger(objcpointer). This means ObjC objects should "po" the same in Swift as they do in Objective-C
  - the object is actually a Swift object. In this case, LLDB uses its own data formatters to print the object, with a few minor tweaks to give a "po"-esque look, but no matter what protocols your object implements, they are ignored

As a future enhancement, the idea is that LLDB will be able to ask the Swift standard library toDebugString(object), and let the Swift library handle the details of what the operations means - much like NSPrintForDebugger() in the Objective-C world.

In this enhanced universe, the Standard Library's contract could very well be that implementing Printable, or DebugPrintable, would affect the result of toDebugString(). LLDB would automatically catch on because it's just delegating the responsibility.

Even in such an enhanced universe, your mileage in REPL mode will vary because of limitations of the JIT. Incidentally, the same limitation makes it impossible for you to define a type in a playground and customize the way it's presented (that would require implementing at least one of the Reflectable/Mirror protocols)

Comment: But *all* objects in Swift are Objective-C objects -- all objects can be used with the Objective-C runtime (not all members may be available to Objective-C; but the object itself is just as good an object as any other object)

Comment: Well, for one structs and enums are not objects in that sense. But, yes, let me be a little more specific: the former behavior applies to instances of @class types *imported* from Objective-C

Comment: Actually **no** Swift class is an Objective-C class. You make them Objective-C classes by making subclasses of an Objective-C class, such as `NSObject`, or by declaring the class preceded by `@objc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
dump(object)
```

Se more about it [here](http://swift-ios.co/standard-functions-in-swift/)